# remove absolute path using sed command

Tags: bash, sed

I have file which contain following context like

```
abc...
include /home/user/file.txt'
some text
```

I need to remove include and also complete path after include.

I have used following command which remove include but did not remove path.

sed -i -r 's#include##g' 'filename'

I am also trying to understand above command but did not understand following thing ( copy paste from somewhere)

```
i - modify file change
r - read file 
s-  Need input
g - Need input
```

Comment: What about using `basename` to get the file name and strip the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$ sed '/^include /s/.*//g' file.txt
abc...

some text
```

It remove all the texts in a line which starts with `include`. `s` means substitute. so `s/.*//g` means replace all the texts with null.`g` means global. The substitution will be applied  globally.

OR

```
$ sed '/^include /d' file.txt
abc...
some text
```

`d` means delete.

It deletes the line which starts with `include`. To save the changes made(inline edit), your commands should be

```
sed -i '/^include /s/.*//g' file.txt
sed -i '/^include /d' file.txt
```

Comment: what is s and g option

Comment: to save the changes made, your command should be `sed -i '/^include/s/.*//g' file.txt` and `sed -i '/^include/d' file.txt
`

Comment: What is difference between two sed command what is best to use

Comment: If you want to delete all the texts only then use the first command otherwise use the second command to delete the whole line.first command leaves an empty line but the second won't.

Comment: Thanks for detail info. if possible, Can you point out me what is wrong with my command.if I have read all comment than above command should work

Comment: sed 's#regex#replace#' so in the regex part, you included  only the string include and in replacement part you wrote nothing.so it replaced the string include with nothing(include string got deleted)

Comment: If you use used with -r option ie, regex option you don't need to escape paranthesis.

Comment: I also used in following way but did not work can u suggest me any modification in command  s#^include##g . It did not work and what should be correct way to work

Comment: Try /inclde/ s#.*##g or only sed 's#include.*##g'

Comment: Sorry commenting through my mobile.

Comment: I found small issue with this command . if I use this, it is also replacing if I have include1 in the file. is it possible to delete exact match word

Answer (score 1):

I your case if you just want to delete the second line, you can use:

```
sed -i '2d' file
```

If you want to explore something about linux commands then man pages are there for you.
Just go to terminal and type:

```
man sed
```

as per your question,  The above command without -i will show the file content on terminal by deleting the second line from the input file. However, the input file remains unchanged. To update the original file or to make the changes permanently in the source file, use the -i option.

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX] :

              edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)

-r or --regexp-extended :
              option is to use extended regular expressions in the script.

 s/regexp/replacement/ :

              Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If  success‐
              ful,   replace  that  portion  matched  with  replacement.   The
              replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that
              portion  of  the  pattern  space  which matched, and the special
              escapes \1 through \9 to refer  to  the  corresponding  matching
              sub-expressions in the regexp.

 g G    :     Copy/append hold space to pattern space.
```

Answer (score 1):

## `grep -v`

This is not about learning `sed`, but as an alternative (and short) solution, there is:

```
grep -v '^include' filename_in
```

Or with output redirection:

```
grep -v '^include' filename_in > filename_out
```

`-v` option for `grep` inverts matching (hence printing non-matching lines).
For simple deletion that's what I'd use; if you have to modify your path after the `include`, stick with `sed` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to just delete the line:

```
awk '/^include/ {next}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -r 's#include##g' 'filename'
```

`-i`: you directly modify the treated file, by default, sed read a file, modify the content via stdout (the original file stay the same).

`-r`: use of extended regular expression (and not reduce to POSIX limited one).This is not necessary in this case due to simple POSIX compliant action in action list (the `s###` string).

`s#pattern#NewValue#`: substitute in current line the pattern (Regular Expression) with "Newvalue" (that also use internal buffer or specific value). The traditionnal form is `s///` but in this case, using `/` in path (pattern or new value) an alternate form is used to avoid to escape all `/` in pattern or new value

`g`: is an option of `s###` that specify change EVERY occurence and not the first (by default)

so here it replace ANY occurence of `include` by nothing (remove) directly into your file

Comment: Thanks.I was looking infomration why it is not delete complete path. or if I have to use same command How can  I achieve same functionality

Comment: path is no deleted because you only select `include`and not `include.*` that take all the end of line also. But this will replace the line by an empty one, not delete the line. In this case use `/include/d` that delete any line that contain "include"

Answer (score 0):

As per the `Avinash Raj` solution you got what you want but you want some explaination about some parameter used in `sed` command

First one is

**command: s for substitution**

With the `sed` command the substitute command `s` changes all occurrences of the regular expression into a new value. A simple example is changing "my" in the "file1" to "yours" in the "file2" file:

```
sed s/my/yours/ file1 >file2
```

The character after the `s` is the delimiter. It is conventionally a slash, because this is what `ed, more, and vi` use. It can be anything you want, however. If you want to change a pathname that contains a slash - say `/usr/local/bin to /common/bin` - you could use the backslash to quote the slash:

```
sed 's/\/usr\/local\/bin/\/common\/bin/' <old >new
```

**/g - Global replacement**

`Replace all matches, not just the first match.`

If you tell it to change a word, it will only change the first occurrence of the word on a line. You may want to make the change on every word on the line instead of the first then add a `g` after the last delimiter and use the work-around:

**Delete with d**

`Delete the pattern space; immediately start next cycle.`

You can delete line by specifying the line number. like

```
sed '$d' filename.txt
```

It will remove last line of file

```
sed '2 d' file.txt
```

It will delete second line of file.

**-i option**

`This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place. GNU sed does this by creating a temporary file and sending output to this file rather than to the standard output.`

To modify file actully you can use `-i` option without it `sed` command repressent changes on `stdout` not actual file. You can take backup of original file before modification by using `-i.bak` option.

**-r option**

`--regexp-extended`

Use extended regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions. Extended regexps are those that egrep accepts; they can be clearer because they usually have less backslashes, but are a GNU extension and hence scripts that use them are not portable.